# Android market ranking and active installs

Tags: android

I have a game which has been available since July 2010. I've had 18,000 total downloads so far and average rating is 3.5.

When I search the arcade category it comes out below a lot of other apps which have both lower downloads and a lower ranking. For example one that is some 20 positions higher has 1,000 - 5,000 downloads and 2.5 stars.

My conclusion to this is that the active installs percentage weights very highly, mine is at 21%.

Now this low percentage is explainable by two things

1) Early versions of the app were 'beta' and it took a while to fix on all devices to work stable.

2) This was a 'demo' product, so I suspect a lot of people uninstalled due to completing the demo.

I have since updated the app to be ad-supported. In theory people would be more likely to keep this, and also the game has many more features that the original version. I am considering re-releasing the app as a new apk. This should reset the stats and hopefully give me a higher position that I currently occupy. I suspect the current uninstall rate is nowhere near as low because I have been monitoring the active installs vs recent downloads and it is much higher.

Has anyone got any experience of doing this, and was it a good idea? I don't want to abandon the current version as there are still 4000+ users on it. I guess I could release an update pointing them to the newer version.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions, not marketing or promotion questions.

Comment: @CommonsWare: It is an interesting question, and probably relevant for many software developers. SO is not exclusively about code problems; for instance, 1239 questions are about career development. Regarding this specific question: SO has 85 questions on software marketing.

Comment: But the fact that there are other questions here should have nothing to do with the question wheter they (and this one) _belongs_ here? That would be better answered by referal to the FAQ's "What kind of questions can I ask here?"....